# Update Remix.run component after change of some different variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, remix, remix.run

When I've been developing in pure React.js, I was used to store some data into Redux and set some component to listen to changes in Redux (with `useSelector` ([source](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors)). But now I am doing facing the same problem but in different technology. In Remix there's no useSelector with Redux. Yes there is possible to use `useState` but it have to be under one parent compopnent but I don't have this structure. So is there any solution to force component to re-render when some independent state changes?
Thanks

I've tried to call some function to force re-render but that's not 'nice' solution. I've even thinked about storying data into localStorage/cookies but when they change, components doesn't update (I understand why it doesn't force re-render but I've tried it...).

Answer (score 0):

Redux should still work normally even with Remix, as it's just a state manager. It's entirely possible that all you have is a configuration issue with Redux *(I personally dislike Redux for how needlessly complex it into use)*

You could try React's own Context for storing state that could be used by several components. Other proven state managers are the likes of [jotai](https://jotai.org) or [zustand](https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs).

Even regular state could work because there's always a root component in remix: i.e. root.tsx.

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Other ways to update various parts of the UI is using nested routes and . You can access parent and child page data with [useLoaderData()](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/hooks/use-fetcher).